# SSIS Chunk Timeout Errors exporting data using CData Snowflake Source

Tags: ssis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cdata-drivers

Anyone run into this error?  How do I resolve, not getting much guidance from `cdata` or `snowflake`.

> Error: 0x0 at ADI_PRODUCT, CData Snowflake Source: Get data error: Retrieved Chunk#0 Timeout.
> Error: 0xC0047062 at ADI_PRODUCT, CData Snowflake Source [279]: System.Exception: Get data error: Retrieved Chunk#0 Timeout.
> at CData.SSIS.Snowflake.SSISSourceComponent.PrimeOutput(Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPrimeOutput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, IDTSBuffer100[] buffers, IntPtr ppBufferWirePacket)
> Error: 0xC0047038 at ADI_PRODUCT, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on CData Snowflake Source returned error code 0x80131500.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this, but given the fact that there appears to be a **timeout** retrieving data (presumably from Azure's cloud storage), it might be worthwhile to verify that you are not encountering a networking issue (eg. firewall) by verifying connectivity via Snowflake's [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html) utility. Just a thought.